# modify if else condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var filterBy = window.location.search.substring(10);
if(filterBy !==""){
    if(filterBy ==='all'){
        $('#filterItems').find('[data-type]').show();
    }else{
        $('#filterBy li').removeClass('active');
        $('#filterBy').find('li[data-filter= "'+ filterBy + '"]').addClass('active');
        $('#filterItems').find('[data-type]').hide().end().find('[data-type*="' + filterBy + '"]').show();
    }
}
```

I want to make it optimized. filterBy==="" and filterBy === all. I feel its checking two times for condition. I want to have only condition check

Answer (score 4):

If `filterBy` equalt to `"all"`, is not empty. So you don't need to check it too.

```
if (filterBy === 'all') {
    // your code here
} else if (filterBy !== '') {
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this.

```
if (filterBy === "" || filterBy === 'all'){
   // if condition is met
} else {
  // if condition is not met
}
```